# Swift add subview within function

Tags: swift, subview

I am attempting to display a loading subview when a button is pressed. I am not sure why but the subview only appears when the alert view is displayed. I would like to have the loading screen displayed as soon as the function begins.

What is causing this and how would I rectify it?

```
 @IBAction func registerManual(_ sender: Any) {

        // Check the validity of the inputs
        let isValid = manualRegistration().validate(firstName: "\(String(describing: firstName.text!))", lastName: "\(String(describing: lastName.text!))", email: "\(String(describing: email.text!))", password: "\(String(describing: password.text!))", dob: dobSelected)

        if(isValid == "success"){
            let loadingScreen = xibLoad().loadingScreen()
            loadingScreen.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
            loadingScreen.tag = 100
            view.addSubview(loadingScreen)

            // Submit to backend.
            let params = "firstname=\(escpae().url(string: firstName.text!))&lastname=\(escpae().url(string:lastName.text!))&email=\(escpae().url(string:email.text!))&dob=\(escpae().url(string: selectedDateText.text!))&password=\(escpae().url(string:password.text!))&currency=\(currency)&language=\(language)&region=\(region)"

            let resultArray = serverCall().post(endPoint: "registermanual.php?", params: "\(params)", fromViewController: self)    

            if(resultArray.count > 0 && resultArray[0]["error"] == nil){
                self.defaults.set("\(resultArray[0]["token"]!)", forKey: "token")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"goLoading", sender: self)
                }
            }
            if(resultArray.count > 0 && resultArray[0]["error"] != nil){
                alert().show(title: "ERROR", message: "\(resultArray[0]["error"]!)", button: "OK", viewc: self)
            }
        }else{
            alert().show(title: "Oops!", message: "\(isValid)", button: "OK", viewc: self)
        }
    }
```

Loading Screen:

```
class loadingScreen: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var gifView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //custom logic goes here
         gifView.loadGif(name: "loading")
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your code for your loadingScreen. It seems like it doesnt have a width value?

Comment: It **manualRegistration** an api call or local validation ??

Comment: manualRegistration is a local call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this , it would be a matter of milli seconds [ depending in validation time ] even if you add the subview out of the if statement , but it will prevent any user event

```
@IBAction func registerManual(_ sender: Any) {


   loadingScreen.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
   loadingScreen.tag = 100
   view.addSubview(loadingScreen)
   // view.layoutSubviews() don't call it directly

    // Check the validity of the inputs
    let isValid = manualRegistration().validate(firstName: "\(String(describing: firstName.text!))", lastName: "\(String(describing: lastName.text!))", email: "\(String(describing: email.text!))", password: "\(String(describing: password.text!))", dob: dobSelected)
    if(isValid == "success"){
```

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan, unfortunately that does not resolve the issue. Interestingly if i remove the API call 'resultArray' the loading screen appears as I would expect. i suspect it may be to do with this but I would have assumed the subview would appear before this function is started.

Comment: where do you call it in main thread , is so , make it in a background thread as it will affect other tasks of the main thread specifically adding the loading view

Comment: Hi, That has resolved the issue! thank you very much!